# Копирование Excel файла через VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Всем привет. С VBA голову сломал. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Есть папка. В ней лежит excel файл("Имя A") его нужно копировать в эту же папку каждые 4 секунды, но с другим именем ("Имя B") так, чтобы файл "Имя В" заменялся на новый и не открывался при этом. Есть бот который будет из файла "Имя В" забирать данные. С открытым файлом бот работать не может, а данные как то нужно обновлять. За ранее огромное всем спасибо за помощ

Comment: Эммм... надо копировать исходный файл из VBA-кода в самом этом файле, что ли? ну так имеется `Workbook.SaveCopyAs`.

Comment: Копировать исходный файл при помощи VBA раз в 4 секунды. В папку с исходным файлом.

Comment: *Копировать исходный файл при помощи VBA* Блин, где находится VBA-код, который это должен делать? в исходном файле? в третьем файле?

Comment: VBA файл в исходном

Comment: Ну тогда я ссылку на метод дал - что ещё нужно-то?

Comment: Я протестирую вариант и отпишу вам. Спасибо за ответы во всяком случае

Comment: Метод работает. Огромная вам благодарность !